# Redash in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redash

Can anyone list out the steps for running redash in AWS EC2?
The redash home page provides the AMI ids but does not give clear information on what the steps are after the EC2 instance is UP.

Goal: Need to run redash in an AWS EC2 instance

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit the EC2 console of your AWS Account
2. Select "Launch Instances"
3. Under the section, select AMIs, select Community AMIs tab.
4. Copy paste the required Redash AMI ID [from this page](https://redash.io/help/open-source/setup#aws)
5. Select required configurations and launch the instance